# CrafterCMS: How to use crafter engine properties in an application-context bean?

Tags: content-management-system, spring-jdbc, crafter-cms

I am connecting to an external database with a class that extends `JdbcTemplate`. My problem is that I can't use the `globalProperties` of the Groovy API because of the Jdbc.

I added these properties I needed in the **server-config.properties**:

```
studio.db.driverClassName
studio.db.url
studio.db.username
studio.db.password
```

I am trying to access them in my **application-context.xml** with this:

```
<bean id="jdbc" class="com.dbJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="datasource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${studio.db.url}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${studio.db.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${studio.db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${studio.db.password}"/>
</bean>
```

I receive this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception 
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '${studio.db.driverClassName}'

How do I access the properties from my bean correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" parent="crafter.properties"/>` in your site `application-context.xml`, like is shown in here https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/site-administrators/engine/engine-site-configuration.html#id3. That lines gives you access to Engine's global properties.